# Ansible win_updates module not fully updating

Tags: windows-10, ansible

I have this playbook

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  tasks:
    - name: "Install all updates without a scheduled task"
      win_updates:
        category_names:
          - Application
          - Connectors
          - CriticalUpdates
          - DefinitionUpdates
          - DeveloperKits
          - FeaturePacks
          - Guidance
          - SecurityUpdates
          - ServicePacks
          - Tools
          - UpdateRollups
          - Updates
        reboot: yes
```

To update several computers, running windows 10 inside a Windows 2012 Server domain, and ansible was enabled in those hosts using the following command:

```
     @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://github.com/ansible/ansible/raw/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1'))"
```

I run this playbook several times until no updates are available to be installed. However, if a user logged in that host go to Settings > Windows Updates and clicks the "Check for updates" button, the host can find an install updates, even when win_updates said that no updates where remaining.

I want to know if there is a problem with the playbook or the configuration, or just this is the way that win_updates work.

**Update**

It seems to happen with cumulative updates. Nobody has this problem?

Comment: (Disclaimer: I never used any `win_*` modules with ansible). Did you run the module with `state: searched` as advised in [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_updates_module.html) to get the list of all categories ? Are you sure the updates that users are finding manually are not in a category you didn't include in your list ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. After running the playbook in 45 computers, I logged in and click "Check for updates" button in them, to find out that a cumulative update (category "Updates") was available to be installed. I saw this behavior several times, always with cumulative updates. Running the command with state: searched didn't find the remaining updates. I tried that with no luck.